# How to change Solution to Response in latex exam environment

Tags: exam

I am preparing response to comments given by the reviewers for my thesis. I wrote each of their comment as a question using exam document class. For giving response to their comments I am using answer option. So the format is somewhat like this:

```
 \documentclass[answers]{exam}
\begin{document}
\section{First Reviewer Comments}
    \begin{questions}
    \question First comment.
    \begin{solution}
    My response.
    \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

It prints [Solution: My response] inside a box.
I want to replace "Solution" by "Response". How to do this ?